# Как перенести char[] в CharSequence[]?

Tags: java

Есть функция, которая принимает CharSequence[] (это AlertBuilder.setItems в Android), нужно ей передать char[]. Как привести или перевести одно в другое?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще говоря, `String` является также `CharSequence`, соответственно, способ может быть таким:

```
// char[] array = ...
CharSequence sequence = new String(array);
```

---

Как альтернативный вариант **без дополнительного копирования:**

```
CharSequence sequence = java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваш способ очень сложен. Зачем так запутанно? Почему бы просто

```
char[] array = "My test".toCharArray();  // исходный массив символов
CharSequence[] seq = new CharSequence[] { new String(array) };
```

Или (без копирования чаров)

```
char[] array = "My test".toCharArray();  // исходный массив символов
CharSequence[] seq = new CharSequence[] { CharBuffer.wrap(array) };
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ

```
List<char[]> l = Arrays.asList(from);
CharSequence[] to = l.toArray(new CharSequence[l.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как насчет эффективности, но работает (и мне понятно как)

```
    CharSequence  [] to = new CharSequence [from.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
        to[i] = ""+from[i];
```

Answer (score -1):

Логичнее использовать String как промежуточный тип (и очевиднее).

```
CharSequence cs;
char[] ch="test".toCharArray();
cs=(CharSequence) ch.toString();
```

Comment: ch.toString() - выдаст адрес массива в памяти плюс сигнатуру типа.